# How can a Docker image build locally, but not at remote destination?

Tags: python, docker

We have a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
from ubuntu:trusty

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential g++ libblas-dev liblapack-dev gfortran python-dev python-pip

RUN pip install --upgrade numpy
RUN pip install --upgrade statsmodels
RUN pip install --upgrade flask

COPY . server

WORKDIR server

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT python2 prediction_app.py
```

Locally, these steps complete without incident. However, on our remote target, this step fails:

```
RUN pip install --upgrade statsmodels
```

when pip tries to delete a directory that isn't empty:

```
Found existing installation: six 1.5.2
  Uninstalling six:
    Successfully uninstalled six
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
[... snip many lines ...]
onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 254, in rmtree
os.rmdir(path)
OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty:...
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Two questions:

1. **How is it possible that this works locally and fails remotely?** Shouldn't they both fail the same way or succeed the same way since they both started from the same image? I'm trying to understand what's wrong with my mental model about this.
2. Is there a way to see the failure log? It looks like it was dumped into an incomplete Docker image and I'm not sure how to get at that.

Comment: I don't know if it's related. Since statsmodels doesn't specify the dependencies in a pip compatible way, I would recommend to explicitly apt-get or pip-install scipy, pandas and patsy.

Comment: @user333700 That unfortunately is not an option because the trusty image's scipy is too outdated.

Comment: What operating systems are you running on the local and remote hosts?

Comment: @KevanAhlquist Ubuntu 14.10 on the local host, Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on the remote host.

Comment: Host os should not matter as command executed in docker container. Your could copy log file from latest container created by build (you could find it with docker ps -a): docker cp <name>:/root/.pip/pip.log ./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this issue is due to usage of the docker overlay storage backend.

I've raised a bug for it here: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12327